# How to multiply value from spinner to display in textview2

Tags: textview, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

I would like to know how to take value from a spinner which is displayed in textview1 and multiply it with a double (0.032) so it can display in textview2.

my code is below

```
 double num1 = Integer.parseInt(textView.getText().toString());
    textView2.setText(Double.toString(num1 * 0.032));
    textView2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#F29027"));

 @SuppressLint({"ResourceAsColor", "SetTextI18n"})
private void itemselected() {

    String name = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

    if (name.equals("Select Property")) {
        textView.setText("0.00");
        textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#F29027"));
    }

    if (name.equals("Apartment A3")) {

        textView.setText(Double.toString(380000.00));
        textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#F29027"));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this
textview2.setText(String.valueOf((long)(.032d *
Double.parseDouble(textview.getText().toString()))));